# Why I can't delete the records from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, database

I am pretty new in Microsoft **SQL Server** and I am not so into DB and I have the following problem.

I have to delete all the records that are inside a table named **VulnerabilityReference**

So I executed this statment:

```
delete from VulnerabilityReference;
```

But I obtain this error message and no rows are deleted form my table:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_AlertDocument_Reference_Reference". The conflict occurred in database "DB NAME", table "dbo.VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference", column 'VulnerabilityReferenceId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

What it exactly means? Have I to delete all the records from the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** table before delete the records into my **VulnerabilityReference**?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you are attempting to delete has it's primary key in another table.  You must first remove (or set to null) the column in the other table BEFORE you can delete.  This is called DB Referential integrity.

You can disable constraints (if you have adequate permissions) but I would suggest you not do that.

To remove the link for all records in that other table, you could do this:

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference
  SET VulnerabilityReferenceId = NULL
```

If the AlertDocument table does NOT ALLOW nulls for that column then you'll need to `DELETE` all the VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference records etc... OR `ALTER` the table to ALLOW `NULL`.  Make sure you know what you are about to do...

I am assuming the name of the column in the VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference table, you obviously need to use the correct table and column names.

Comment: from what you see that I have a VulnerabilityAlertDocument on my database? In my previous snippet I have no speack about it.

Comment: ok, i've updated my answer to use the VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference table...

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have an id of a record in VulnerabilityReference related to a AlerDocument table. The error is warning you of this problem and that you can't delete this record if you don't delete first the related records.

I mean the tables in the relation named as FK_AlertDocument_Reference_Reference
You have a relationship between VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference and other table. You can go to this table and find the relationships, find the name beginning with FK. In the properties of this relationship you will see the name of the other table and columns used in this relationship. If you want you can create a diagram, then drop this two tables and you will see in a visual way how the relationship is built

Comment: do you mean the VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference?

Comment: I mean the tables in the relation named as FK_AlertDocument_Reference_Reference
You have a relationship between VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference and other table. I have updated the answer with more information.